# how to pipe results from LS to CD in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pipe, ls

I'd like to ls for the latest created directory in a given directory (we create a new folder for each release) and then cd to that directory. I'd like to create an alias for this so I don't have to remember how to get to the latest directory every time I need to.

Here's what I've tried:

```
ls -ltr ~/workspace/docs/new-docs/Mapper/Documentation/ | tail -1 | cd
cd $(ls -ltr ~/workspace/docs/new-docs/Mapper/Documentation/ | tail -1)
```

the problem seems to be that if I order the results I end up with the permissions on the file as output. Any help is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:

```
$cd `ls -dt ~/workspace/docs/new-docs/Mapper/Documentation/* | head -1`
-bash: cd: drwxr-xr-x: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you did specify the `-l` option to `ls`, which results in long output. Try dropping it.

```
ls -tr ~/workspace/docs/new-docs/Mapper/Documentation/
```

You'll also need to ensure that the path gets prepended to the directory name you want. Do this by adding `*` to the path and specifying the `-d` option to `ls`.

```
ls -dtr ~/workspace/docs/new-docs/Mapper/Documentation/*
```

To improve performance you should also pipe to `head` and not reverse the sort.

```
ls -dt ~/workspace/docs/new-docs/Mapper/Documentation/* | head -1
```

The final command is:

```
cd `ls -dt ~/workspace/docs/new-docs/Mapper/Documentation/* | head -1`
```

Comment: +1 for a thorough answer but it's not working for me. see my update.

Comment: Did you do something silly like alias `ls` to something containing the `-l` option? If so, try using `/bin/ls` in your command instead.

Comment: well i don't know but that seems to have worked!

Comment: actually looks like I had this: `alias ls='ls -n'` I'll remove it. Not even sure what -n does (i inherited a lot of my aliases).

Comment: hmmm...i see: -n, --numeric-uid-gid
              like -l, but list numeric user and group IDs

Answer (score 1):

A couple things to mention:

- `ls -dt [PATH]/*` will also list files; that could be a problem if files are present in the directory.
- you may want to use quotes, in case the directory name contains spaces.

So, a couple more quick options for you:

```
    cd "`ls -dt ~/workspace/docs/new-docs/Mapper/Documentation/*/ | head -1`"
```

or, if supported by your `ls` command,

```
    cd "`ls -t --group-directories-first ~/workspace/docs/new-docs/Mapper/Documentation | head -1`"
```